# complex sql join table

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-4

I have 4 table
`chart`, `chart_detail`, `customer`, `produk`
like this

[image]
[image]

[image]
[image]

I wanna run sql comand to list data in `chart` table

I don't have problem to join `cart` table with `chart detail` & `customer` table
because

`chart.id` = `chart_detail.id_chart`
`chart.id_customer` = `customer.id`

```
DB::table('chart')
    ->join('customer', 'chart.id_customer', '=', 'customer.id')
    ->join('chart_detail', 'chart.id', '=', 'chart_detail.id_chart')->get();
```

but i have problem can't access `nama_produk` 

( in `chart_detail` table there is only `id_produk`)...so i need to join `chart` table with `produk` table

```
DB::table('chart')
    ->join('customer', 'chart.id_customer', '=', 'customer.id')
    ->join('produk', 'produk.id', '=', 'chart_detail.id_produk')
    ->join('chart_detail', 'chart.id', '=', 'chart_detail.id_chart')->get();
```

but i get error like this

```
Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'chart_detail.id_produk' in 'on clause'
```

because in `chart` table there is not available `id_produk` 
`id_produk` available in `chart_detail` table

i wonder how to solve it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You had your joins out of order, hence the error about the unknown column.  Try the following code:

```
DB::table('chart')
    ->join('customer', 'chart.id_customer', '=', 'customer.id')
    ->join('chart_detail', 'chart.id', '=', 'chart_detail.id_chart')
    ->join('produk', 'produk.id', '=', 'chart_detail.id_produk')->get();
```